# Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() - Read and Write Time out error asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Im trying to make a call to an external api [ASP.NET core 3.1]with the following code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
             var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,url);
            var Client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync( );

                Results = await JsonSerializer.
                DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Result>>(responseStream);
            }
       
            else
            {
                Results = Array.Empty<Result>();
            }
    }
```

The code seems to fail on the following line :

var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync( );

The responseStream seems to return Read and Write Time out error, not sure why?
Please assist.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR8Fe.png)

Answer (score 1):

That is normal and does not affect your obtaining of `Results`. You can obtain results as follows.

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions= new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    };
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,url);
        var Client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseStream1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseStream2 = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var results1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Result>>(responseStream1);
            var results2 = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Result>>(responseStream2, jsonSerializerOptions);

        }
        else
        {
           var Results = Array.Empty<Result>();
        }
    return View();
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Yinqiu,  I  finally got this to work using the following code:
var OracleMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Oracleurl ); OracleMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var Oracleclient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var Oracleresponse = await Oracleclient.SendAsync(OracleMessage);
if (Oracleresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
var OresponseStream1 = await Oracleresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Odata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OracleData>(OresponseStream1);
}

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Get()
    {
           var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            var httpClient= _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
            var response=httpClient.GetAsync(url);
             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Result>>(stringData);
            } else
            {
             ...error
            }        
}
```

Comment: Hi, still getting the same error. thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Yes, i do get results when i use Postman.

Comment: This code was tested without any problems at hundreds APIs. Can you show your url please. You can hide the midle of it.

Comment: Sergey, Thank you very much for all your assistance, i finally got it to work with the following code :


var OracleMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Oracleurl ); OracleMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
var Oracleclient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var Oracleresponse = await Oracleclient.SendAsync(OracleMessage);
if (Oracleresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
var OresponseStream1 = await Oracleresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Odata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OracleData>(OresponseStream1);
}